# PostGIS Installation "could not open extension control file"

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I've been scouring posts trying to figure out how to resolve this issue - `could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

I'm installing PostgreSQL and PostGIS with `apt-get install postgresql-12 postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3` into a Docker container running `python:latest`. I'd initially been running Alpine however it seemed there were a number of issues getting PostGIS installed successfully on Alpine distributions.

I've located the file with `find /usr -name postgis.control` under `/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control`. I've attempted to move this to the directory PostGIS expects, but I'm still seeing the same error.

It's been driving me totally mad!

Any help is appreciated, and happy to answer any questions that will help me find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was never able to resolve this issue, so I ended up switching to the official postGIS docker image which worked flawlessly. Would recommend it to anyone else in a similar situation.

Comment: Ironically, I switched away from the Docker image to a local install for development due to relentless issues with mounts. For Mac users, look into homebrew. https://morphocode.com/how-to-install-postgis-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but installing PostGIS on the ubuntu machine worked for me.

```
apt-get install postgis*
```

After the installation above, I was able to create the extension as expected.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```